# How to generate number which exactly has seven divisors?

Tags: c++, algorithm, prime-factoring

For a homework assignment, I need the logic to find a series of numbers from 1 to 1000 which have exactly seven divisors.

(Ideally, the code could be easily modified to generate prime numbers.)

Comment: One starting point to consider would be that to get an odd number of divisors, it must be a perfect square.

Comment: @Gabe: from what I know it is always counted unless explicitly excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need loop (for loop) from `for n = 1 to 1000` and inside this loop another loop `for m = 1 to n` inside this loop test if `n/m = integer (no remainder)` and if it is increment the div counter.
At the end of second loop check if div counter is 7 if it is write the number on the screen.

EDIT: for prime numbers the div counter must be 2!

Comment: +1 because **it also can easily be modified to generate prime numbers**

Comment: @liori: Just a simple brute-force algorithem. It is possible to improve it, but why for only 1000 numbers?

Comment: For 1000 numbers you should notice that 1000^(1/6) is just little more than 3. This means the only numbers less than 1000 that have 7 divisors can be 2^6 and 3^6. How much time would you need to type your algorithm?

Comment: @liori: Agree, but this is homework and he need logic which can be easily modified to generate prime numbers. So?

Answer (score 9):

Take a prime number `p`. Calculate `p^6`. Its only divisors will be: `1`, `p`, `p^2`, `p^3`, ..., `p^6`.

Comment: int sevendivis(){ return 2*2*2*2*2*2; }

Answer (score 7):

A number with the factorisation

```
n = product(p_i ^ k_i)
```

will have

```
d = product(k_i + 1)
```

divisors (see [divisor function in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)).  This shows `n` may only have one prime factor, and this prime factor must be raised to the power of 6.  So take the sixth power of an arbitrary prime number.

Answer (score 2):

The Logic would be that the number would **be both perfect Square and Perfect cube.**

You must be Knowing that a number which has prime factor form as N=N1^a * N2^b;
Where N1 and N2 are prime numbers has a*b factors or divisors.

Thus for 7 factors number must be of the form N=a^6 where a is a prime number .

for e.g 2^6 (64) , 3^6 (729).

**EDIT:** With this logic it would be quite easier to generate numbers quicly .You can easily generate perfect squares and perfect cube <1000.And check both the lists for common numbers.